# Multiple rows returned trying to select specific row in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to return a value from field tid in a specific row in Oracle SQL but I am getting a weird behavior.

First, I tried this:

```
 select tid from
 (select tid, rownum as rn from
      (select tid from Train))
 where rn=5;
```

and the value in row 5 is successfully returned. However, when I try to randomize the value to take the row with rownum from 1 to 15 by doing the following:

```
 select tid from
 (select tid, rownum as rn from
      (select tid from Train))
 where rn=round(dbms_random.value(1,15));
```

more rows are returned, not just one. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `dbms_random()` is called for each row, so it can generate duplicate results.  Instead, if you want one random row, try something like this:

```
select tid
from (select tid,
             row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value()) as seqnum
      from Train
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This will always return the row with "seqnum = 1", but it will be a random `tid`.

Comment: If the problem is just that `dbms_random()` is called for each row, I guess it would be enough to use an auxiliary variable `aux:=round(dbms_random.value(1, 15))`... Any idea about performance differences between the two solutions?

Comment: @randombee . . . I'm not sure.  If performance is important, it is worth trying it both ways.